# How to resume Oracle JDK updates?

Tags: java, linux, package, ubuntu-14.04

I've stopped receiving updates for Oracle JDK for my KUbuntu 14.04 a couple months ago.
I have installed and configured it previously according to http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html
It worked, but now during update I only see errors:

```
Err https://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized
Err https://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized

W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My currently installed version of java is 1.8.0_91.

Content of */etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-trusty.list*:

```
deb https://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
```

Please, help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem.

Removed repos from my system:

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-trusty.list*
```

Re-added repos:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```